# Receive mic input and process

Tags: c++, linux, audio, microphone

I am writing a small program in C++ that receives mic input and does some simple live audio processing. I have been looking around and the only things I have been able to find that work on Linux are PortAudio, QAudioInput, and fmod.

I am trying to stay away from any super low level programming and use a minimal amount of lines.

Which one of these would fit my needs best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce/). Juce will build on many platforms. JUCE does a lot more than just audio, but it was made with audio programmers in mind. Look at he JUCE demo application and then just chop up the source code from the audio demo to suit your needs. The API documentation is really good also. The abstraction from the low level stuff is good.

Comment: Wow I just downloaded it. How long has it been around and why haven't I heard of it before? This stuff is great!

Comment: It is quite big in the audio development community but hasn't gained much traction with a wider community until recently. I think the lib has been available since about 2004. . . . or maybe 2006. I'm not sure. I've known about it for some time but only checked it out in detail recently and I can't believe i didn't try it earlier. Enjoy!